# Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка(выдает значение от 1 до 99)

Tags: python

Код должен найти минимальное число A при тождественно ложном выражении:

```
((x & 17 ≠ 0) → ((x & A ≠ 0) → (x & 58 ≠ 0))) → ((x & 8 = 0) ∧ (x & A ≠ 0) ∧ (x & 58 = 0))
```

Должны вывестись значения `2 8 10 16 18 24 26 32 34 40 42 48 50 56 58`

```
for A in range(1,100):
    p=[]
    for x in range(1,1000):
        F=(((x&17)!=0)<=(((x&A)!=0) <=((x&58)!=0)))<=(((x&8)==0)and((x&A)!=0)and((x&58)==0))
        p.append(F)
    if all(p)==False:
        print(A)
```

Comment: Что должен делать код?

Comment: непонятно, что должен делать этот код, но очевидно, что  значения вне диапазона 1-99 он выдавать никогда не будет.

Comment: Должен найти минимальное число A при тождественно ложном выражении

Comment: ((x & 17 ≠ 0) → ((x & A ≠ 0) → (x & 58 ≠ 0))) → ((x & 8  = 0) ∧ (x & A ≠ 0) ∧ (x & 58  = 0)) вот выражение

Comment: что означают стрелки в этом выражении?

Comment: @Эникейщик  импликация

Comment: @andreymal Странно. Ну ладно. А то сравниение логических значений на больше-меньше выглядит странно.

Comment: Что в итоге должно вывести то? И почему?

Comment: @Эникейщик должны вывестись значения

Comment: 2 8 10 16 18 24 26 32 34 40 42 48 50 56 58

Comment: Я думаю, причина в том, что ``all(p)==False`` наверняка делает не то, что ты думаешь. ``all(p)`` проверяет, что ВСЕ элементы ``p`` тождественны ``True``. А ``all(p)==False``, соответственно, провряет, что не все равны ``True``, а не то, что все равны ``False``, как ты, возможно, думаешь.

Comment: @andreymal интересно, не знал. В целом редко в реальных задачах сталкиваешься с импликацией.

Answer (score 0):

Замени

```
if all(p)==False:
```

на

```
if not any(p):
```

`all(p)==False` - проверяет, что не все элементы `p` равны True.

`any(p)` - проверяет, что хотя бы один из элементов `p` равен `True`. Соответственно, `not any(p)` проверяет, что ни один из элементов `p` не равен `True`.

Comment: спасибо буду знать теперь)